# Testing IDbCommandInterceptor with InMemoryDatabase for EFCore

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have written an `IDbCommandInterceptor` to intercept calls to EntityFrameworkCore DbContext. Now I would like to write unit tests for the interceptor. I am able to intercept and run custom logic for an actual db (tested with SqlServer and MySql), however when [testing with an `InMemoryDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) (provided by .Net for testing purposes), my interceptor methods are never called.

Here's how I'm setting up my unit test:

`TestDbContext` class:

```
    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }

    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I'm initializing the context in my test:

```
        private TestDbContext GetTestDbContext()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDB")
                .AddInterceptors(new MyInterceptor())
                .Options;
            var context = new TestDbContext(options);

            // Seed data
            context.Users.Add(new User { UserId = 1 });
            context.Users.Add(new User { UserId = 2 });
            context.Users.Add(new User { UserId = 3 });
            context.SaveChanges();

            return context;
        }
```

Now, when I call `SaveChanges()` or do a query on this context, I expect it to invoke my `MyInterceptor`'s overridden `ReaderExecuted()` method the same way it does when I use an actual db.

Am I missing something? Or DbCommandInterceptor does not work with InMemoryDatabase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InMemory provider is not a relational provider, and therefore does not implement DbCommand interceptors. You can use a SQL Server / SQL Server LocalDb / SQlite  database for this kind of testing.